# How to remove rows from a R data frame that have NA in two columns (NA in both columns NOT either one)?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a R data frame df below

```
a   b   c

1   6  NA
2  NA  4
3   7  NA
NA  8  1
4   9  10
NA  NA  7
5   10  8
```

I want to remove the row which has NA in BOTH a & b

My desired output will be

```
a   b  c

1   6  NA
2  NA  4
3   7  NA
NA  8  1
4   9  10
5  10  8
```

I tried something like this below

```
df1<-df[(is.na(df$a)==FALSE & is.na(df$b)==FALSE),]
```

but this removes all the NAs (performs an OR function). I need to do AND operation here.

How do i do it ?

Comment: How about this `which(rowSums(df, na.rm = T)>0)`.

Comment: df[ rowSums( is.na(df[ , 1:2]) ) == 2, ]

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
df1<-df[!(is.na(df$a) & is.na(df$b)), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

using `rowSums`

```
df[!rowSums(is.na(df))==2,]
```

better one by saving a character[1]

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df))!=2,]
```

output:

```
   a  b
1  1  6
2  2 NA
3  3  7
4 NA  8
5  4  9
7  5 10
```

can be generalized using `ncol`

```
df[!rowSums(is.na(df))==ncol(df),]
```

[1] credits: [alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire)

Comment: You could save a character and just use `!=`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix (`is.na(df1)`) and convert that to a logical vector (`rowSums(...) < ncol(df1)`) to subset the rows.

```
df1[rowSums(is.na(df1)) < ncol(df1),]
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
df1[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1, is.na)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
df[!apply(is.na(df),1,all),]
#   a  b
#1  1  6
#2  2 NA
#3  3  7
#4 NA  8
#5  4  9
#7  5 10
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L), b = c(6L, NA, 
7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 10L)), .Names = c("a", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also work:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) != ncol(df)),]

   a  b
1  1  6
2  2 NA
3  3  7
4 NA  8
5  4  9
7  5 10
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is basically the same with other replies.

Considering any dataset with a specific row having all NAs, the sum of `!is.na(ROW)` will always be zero. So you just have to take out that row.

So you can just do:

```
df1 = df[-which(rowSums(!is.na(df))==0),]
```